# Access xfs quota info from NFS client

Tags: linux, centos, nfs, quota, xfs

I've got an xfs filesystem (on a Centos 6.4 server) mounted via NFS on a client server (Centos 6.3). I can't seem to access the quota info from the client. It simply returns nothing for `xfs_quota -c quota ...` or `xfs_quota -xc report ...` or `xfs_quota -c print`

I need for users to be able to check their quotas from this client (a cluster head node), but I don't use user quotas for this FS, but instead project quotas.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Oops - should have posted this to Server Fault. Seems there's no way for me to do this myself?

Comment: You may press "flag" and then press Other.  A moderator will be notified who will be able to move the question on your behalf.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for CentOS7 was to install `quota` package and enable the service on the file server:

```
yum install quota
systemctl enable rpc-rquota
systemctl start rpc-rquota
```

Then on the client the `quota` command returned user quota information. Previously I received "Connection refused" error:

```
$ quota
quota: error while getting quota from XXX.XXX.XX.XX:/XXXX/XXXX for XXXX (id XXXX): Connection refused
```

**References**

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1207239
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/nfs-serverconfig#sf2-nfs-accessing-rpc-quote-through-a-firewall

Answer (score 0):

So, as regards checking soft quota, try this one (works for me, NFS-over-XFS project quota):

> df -h $HOME # strange as it seems...

Comment: This only reports disk usage. It does not inform user as to whether they exceed quota and grace period. Also, `df` make take a while as it needs to crawl over entire directory tree.

Comment: @Vince df does not crawl over the directory tree and it's fast! And contrary to what you would normally expect, it actually does not only report the disk usage. It reports your quota (yes, it IS counter intuitive, as you normally use df to check the disk usages). Try it!

Comment: @isarandi: thanks for helping setting the record straight ;-)