# Check XFS project quota on NFS client

Tags: centos7, nfs, disk-space-utilization, xfs, quota

I am implementing project quotas on a file server (Centos 7.8.2003) that has data volumne formatted using XFS. File access to this server will occur using NFS. I know how to check user quotas on the NFS client using the `quota` command (see [Access xfs quota info from NFS client](https://serverfault.com/questions/560844/access-xfs-quota-info-from-nfs-client)). However, the `quota` command in Centos does not have a flag to check project quota. Is there another tool or method I can use to check project quota from an NFS client? Alternatively, I can run a `cron` job on the file server to populate a text file with this information; however, I prefer to know if this can be done more elegantly.

Thanks,

Vince

Answer (score 0):

I would use [xfs_quota](https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_quota):

```
 xfs_quota -c free -h
```

as a regular user (*-c free* executes the *free* command, just like *df*, with the output in human--readable form, *-h*), or

```
xfs_quota -x -c report -p -h
```

as an administrator, concentrating on projects (*-p*), again in human-readable form (*-h*).

Comment: Thanks. Can `xfs_quota` report usage from a XFS filesystem that is mounted using NFS?